# IE 8 & 9 video playback issue with JWPlayer Ver 5.x

Tags: internet-explorer, jwplayer

JW Player Videos won't play on Internet explorer version 8 & 9,here is an reference link:
[Link to page](http://www.mindtree.com/insights/videos/agile-way-life-mindtree-usdc-gainesville)

It shows up to be broken all the time. Type of video files : flv or mp4. We tried adding .htaccess media types but won't work still in IE 8 & 9 + other browsers(Safari/Chrome/Firefox).

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: This plays in IE for me, did you fix the issue?